# Proof of existence of lower-order Symmetric subgroups of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, symmetric-groups

I'm wondering how to prove that, for every pair of natural numbers $\{m,n\}\in \mathbb{N}$, $m\leq n$, there is a subgroup $G\lhd S_n$ such that $G\cong S_m$.
I attempted what i think is a valid proof, that writes like this:

Suppose $\tau:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}_{<m}$, and that $G\lhd S_n$ is the subgroup generated by permutations of the form
$$\sigma=
\pmatrix{1&...&m&m+1&...&n\\\tau(1)&...&\tau(m)&m+1&...&n}$$
Evidently, every permutation $\sigma\in G$ leaves the places $m+1$ to $n$ unchanged. There exists an homomorphism $i:G\rightarrow S_m$ given precisely by
$$i(\sigma)=\pmatrix{1&...&m\\\tau(1)&...&\tau(m)}$$
Since every two functions with the same domain, range and output of $\tau$ must be equal, then $i^{-1}:S_m\rightarrow G$ must exist, and hence, $i$ is a bijective homomorphism. Finally, since $\tau$ was chosen arbitrarily, for every $\{\sigma,\pi\}\in S_n$, we can choose $\tau_{\sigma},\tau_{\pi}$ such that:
$$i(\sigma\circ\pi)=\pmatrix{1&...&m\\\tau(1)&...&\tau(m)}$$
$$=\pmatrix{1&...&m\\\tau_\sigma(1)&...&\tau_\sigma(m)}\pmatrix{1&...&m\\\tau_\pi(1)&...&\tau_\pi(m)}$$
$$=i(\sigma)\circ i(\pi)$$
Since $i(\sigma\circ\pi)=i(\sigma)\circ i(\pi)$ is a bijective homomorphism, then, it is an isomorphism, and thus $G\cong S_m$.

Is this proof ok? Is the bijection demonstration loose? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: $G\triangleleft S_n$ (second paragraph) is incorrect. For $n\geq 5$, the only *normal* subgroups of $S_n$ are trivial, all of $S_n$, and $A_n$.

Comment: It is simpler to embed $S_m$ into $S_n$ by "extending" any $\tau\in S_m$ to fix all $i\gt m$, as you do in the second paragraph. As this is a one-to-one homomorphism, it induces an isomorphism of $S_m$ with its image, which is a subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: Thanks! So i should interchange the normal subgroup notation $\lhd$ with the inclusion notation $\subseteq$, as in $G\subseteq S_n$?

Comment: Subgroup notation, $\leq$, is what you should use.

Comment: Your notation is odd: $\{ m,n\}\notin\Bbb N$.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a self-taught mathematics student, so i might notate things strangely. If you could suggest another notation, i would appreciate it.